# How to use margin top between input and span

Tags: css, vue.js

I am using vue and I wrote a simple code.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input />
    <span class="span-text">Hi</span>
  </div>
</template>

// index.css

.span{
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

I want to put the space between input and span. 
But this margin-top doesn't work. How can I solve this problem? Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: display:inline-block to the span?

Comment: As @BhojendraRauniyar mentioned, span is referred to in CSS by just span and not .span (as all other HTML tags, such as div, h1, etc.). That being said, why use a span and not a div? a div is by default in display: block and will react to margin-top better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your span as a block so the margin will be applied

```
    span{
      display: block;
      margin-top: 3px;
    }
```

Comment: Hi.. A code snippet would make a much better answer.

Comment: Awesome!! Only one correction - span and not .span (I already edited it)

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to a Vue playground in codesandbox.io and I positioned the input above the span, from what you wrote it seems this is the default state you are in and now I gave 3px margin to the span below the input like so, and there you have [it in this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-cccy3)

It seems to work as it is supposed to be the span has 3 pixels space from the top between itself and the input.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <input>
    <span class="span-text">Hi</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App"
};
</script>

<style>
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
span {
  margin-top: 3px;
}
</style>
```

If you have another expected behavior please share so we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is really because the span is an inline element.
And an inline element could have some layout limitations, like adding the y-axis margin that you've mentioned.

You can read more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements

That's why it works when you change its display property from `inline`.